# Impact of updating Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to sort out updating server software to fix some found security issues, but before I do, I need to make sure that this won't affect the website that's currently running. I know for example updating PHP can cause issues with deprecated function use. I'm doing this on a server that I have had no previous involvement with, so I cannot account for code quality and am doing a separate review for PHP.

Does updating Apache have a similar potential problems? we'll be updating from Apache 2.2.11?

Comment: This is where your testbed comes into play.

Comment: Just test it and you'll see. There's no other way.

Comment: It would help to know what OS you are using, what version of Apache are you at, and what version of Apache are you moving too? Are you staying with the vendor-maintained packages? (A `yum update` on RedHat systems typically isn't a big deal)

Comment: I've been dumped into the middle of this legacy project. there is no testbed at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you running 2.2.x branch and updating to same branch then it should be fairly safe to do so, if you're updating it to 2.4.x then I'd look closer to Changelog, but whatever the case the best thing to do is *TEST* it and don't do it on live (production) system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to be sure unless you test your software on a separate system running the newer version of Apache.